# JList updating with live captured packets info (using jNetPcap) is causing list blanking

Tags: multithreading, jlist, jnetpcap

I am coding app which is capturing packet from 2 NI Cards at the same time in specific thread for them.

I am using jnetPcap and I am getting captured packet in jpackethanler's method nextPacket i need to show info from the current packet in JList but when I use simply defaultListModel and i write model1.addElement(packetinfo) then JList randomly goes in blank.

My code :

```
new Thread(){

    @Override
    public void run(){

    StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder(); // For any error msgs

    int snaplen = 64 * 1024;           // Capture all packets, no trucation  
    int flags = Pcap.MODE_PROMISCUOUS; // capture all packets  
    int timeout = 10 * 1000;           // 10 seconds in millis

    Pcap pcap1 =  
        Pcap.openLive(Variables.getDevice1().getName(), snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf);  

    if (pcap1 == null) {  
        System.err.printf("Error while opening device for capture: "  
            + errbuf.toString());  
        return;  
    }

    PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler1 = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {  

        int count = 1;

        @Override
        public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {  

            // ALL PACKETS FROM DEVICE 1 HERE
            int packetSize = packet.size();
            int packetCount = count++;

            String desc = String.format("No.: %15d | HDRSize : %-4d", packetCount,packetSize);

            device1Model.addElement(desc); // this adds desc to JLIST

        }
    };  

    pcap1.loop(Pcap.LOOP_INFINITE, jpacketHandler1, "");
    pcap1.close();

    }
}.start();
```

What do change to be more smooth and at the same time there will be no packet looses. Because i need to catch every packet for right function of app.

Thank You.